# Error when building Movesense example in android studio. Failed to resolve: :mdslib:1.28 Open File

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, movesense

I was trying to build with android studio the Movesense example called: SensorSample (https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src/30b767ba6329b5de05eb0eda960d5a935bc6aba3/android/samples/SensorSample/?at=master)

but I get the following error:

**Failed to resolve: :mdslib:1.28**
**Open File**

produce by the following line:

```
// Movesense .aar lib
compile(name: 'mdslib', version: '1.28.1(1)-release', ext: 'aar')
```

Have somebody gotten the same error? what version of the .aar should I set?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you missed some repository?
check on your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this error.
When working with libraries in .aar format, it is necessary to put the .aar library in to root directory where the application folder is.